# Multiple .bib files in a separate directory from the main .tex file

Tags: bibliographies, multiple-citations

So, I'm trying to organise my references and noticed that putting all of them in one .bib file is messy. I want to make separate .bib files for each reference.
Now, I know I can use

```
\bibliography{fileA,fileB}
```

But.
I want my .bib files to be in a separate folder from my main .tex document. Which means I need to set a directory for it to access the .bib files. I tried to use

```
\bibliography{main/references/bibfile}
```

but this works only for one .bib file.

Does anyone have an idea how do I go about this problem?

Comment: its usually a pair of external environment settings to a bibliotic library of files ADD which tex (Live, Mac MiK) you are using to your question also helps to know what texmf settings you have made

Comment: `\bibliography{main/references/bibfile,main/references/bibfile2}` should work. What error do you get?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that's exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot (I didn't know I needed to add path for each file separately). Don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\bibliography{main/references/bibfile,main/references/bibfile2}` should work.